# iOS - Incrementing ID number for creating filenames

Tags: ios, objective-c

The application I'm working on creates pdf files and saves them in the device's documents directory. What I'm trying to do is create filenames with unique ID number, for example "invoice76.pdf".

How do I ensure each time the pdf file is created the number is incremented from the previous file name.

I tried using a global int but that obviously resets it each time the application is started.

Comment: presumably your app has preferences the user can change? e.g. some kind of persistent data storage? store your last-used ID number there.

Comment: I don't have user preferences at the moment, but that points me in the right direction, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest solution would be to store it in the [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/). Alternatively, you could save the value in your own [plist file](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/QuickStartPlist/QuickStartPlist.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use this code which works betweeb app restarts:

```
- (void)storeIndex:(NSInteger)index{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //change value to new value
    [defaults setInteger:index forKey:@"pdfIndex"];
    //make save
    [defaults synchronize];
}

- (NSInteger)lastIndex{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger value = [defaults integerForKey:@"pdsIndex"];
    return value;
}

//stores new index and returns its value
- (NSInteger)incrementIndex{
    NSInteger lastIndex = [self lastIndex];
    lastIndex++;
    [self storeIndex:lastIndex];
    return lastIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pull an nsstring timestamp from nsdate, and if saving multiple files at the same time (and you don't want to use a massive timestamp) increment through n in a for loop. This will guarantee a unique ID. Then when loading, sort your array ascending and you have your list.